# Using Quotes for grep Query

Tags: grep

When I do :

```
grep -R "fileName.map" .
```

The grep returns nothing

When I do:

```
grep -R fileName.map .
```

It returns me a lot of lines. Why does the first one not work?

Comment: Both should return _identical_ results.  Perhaps there is more to it than what you've posted in your question.

Comment: @Jotne Your edit _modified_ the commands used by the OP.

Comment: @devnull Strange, I did only add code tags. Looking at at edit history all seems to be fine.

Comment: @Programmer,Did you specify any directory name ?

Comment: @Jotne: no, you didn't just add code tags. You deleted the period at the end which were part of the grep command. That completely changes the meaning of the commands.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the information, I just thought it was the end of the line, stupid me :)